# Different colors in 1 chart in Power BI

Tags: charts, powerbi, bar-chart

I have a chart with bars in Power BI, I also have an average line in it. I want to know if I can change the colours when the bar is above the average. I do know that it's possible to set the colours manually, but when I change f.e. years it doesn't adapt.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

You can do this by creating a stacked column chart which has TWO measures - one formatted for below average values, one formatted for above average values, and only displaying the relevant measure for each item on the chart, based on whether the item value is above or below average.

First create your `Total Value` measure:

```
Total Value = SUM ( 'Table'[Value] )
```

Now create your average measure for all "items" on your chart x-axis:

```
Item Average = 
    AVERAGEX ( 
        ALL ( 'Table'[Item] ),
        [Total Value]
    )
```

Now create two separate measures - one if above average, one if below average. Something like:

```
Value Above Average = 
    IF ( 
        [Total Value] >= [Item Average],
        [Total Value],
        BLANK()
    )
```

and

```
Value Below Average = 
    IF ( 
        [Total Value] < [Item Average],
        [Total Value],
        BLANK()
    )
```

Add both measures to a stacked column chart, and format to suit.

[image: Stacked column chart showing green when above average, red when below average]

See worked example PBIX file here: https://pwrbi.com/so_59250483/

## Option 2

You could also achieve this by creating a measure which dictates the required Hex colour code, based on value.

First create your `Total Value` measure:

```
Total Value = SUM ( 'Table'[Value] )
```

Now create a `Colour vs Average` measure, which states the required hex colour code:

```
Colour vs Average = 
    IF ( 
        [Total Value] > [Item Average],
        "#66AA66", //Green
        "#AA3333" //Red
    )
```

Add `Total Value` as the measure in a Stacked Column chart, and use conditional formatting for the colour code of measure `Total Value` - format by `Field Value` based on field `Colour vs Average`

Another example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_59250483_opt2/

Comment: I've added a second option, using just one value measure, and conditional formatting